# Undefined method - passing a value from one view to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in a view similar to this:

```
<%= form_tag("mystuff/new", method: "get") do %>

    <% @accesses.each do |access| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:cost, access.cost) %>
        <%= label_tag  :label,access.label, :class=>"control-label" %>
        <%= label_tag :costlabel, access.cost, :class=>"control-label" %> <%= label_tag :costlabel2, "Euros", :class=>"control-label" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= submit_tag "Go" %>

<% end %>
```

My controller has:

```
    helper_method :amount

    def new
      @amount = params[:cost]
    end
```

and the view of  mystuff/new has a line like:

```
    <div class="row-fluid offset1">Stuff: <%= amount -%> </div>
```

I get Error undefined method `amount'. What I want to do is pass the value of the radio button to the next view, but I don't want to use a database. What's the proper way to do that in rails?

Comment: You are missing a `@` here. `@amount`

Comment: Do you have method name amount? in controller_helper.rb?

Comment: If your goal is to not use an instance variable (i.e., `@amount`) then you need an actual `amount` method. Without an `attr_accessor` (reader) or a manually-defined method you just have an instance variable.

Comment: @MurifoX: you should write it as an answer so I can close the question. That was it. I was missing a @...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a @ here. `@amount`.